# Word referring to all letters with the long ē sound

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pronunciation-vs-spelling, sounds

I read something a while back that defined all letters pronounced- and phonetically ending-with a long /ē/, i.e.:

- Bee
- Cee
- Dee
- Ee
- Gee
- Pee
- Tee
- Vee
- Zee

I can no longer find the aforementioned reference; Google has been challenging.

Do you know of a word to describe this set of letters? Is there a reference that categorizes letter pronunciations this way?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined" all letters pronounced...?  Do you mean that all letters fitting that description are called the __________ letters?

Comment: "Thoughts?" What kind of question are you asking? Are you asking just to agree or disagree, or are you asking for a relevant reference for this or what?

Comment: @KristinaLopez, yes. That is what I was trying to say. Thank you.

Comment: @Mitch, a relevant reference would be good. If you know of a word, that would be good. Whatever help you can provide. I'd love to know a word.

Comment: Other terms. [This article](http://www.speechtechmag.com/Articles/Archives/The-Human-Factor/The-Alpha-Bail-29815.aspx) calls similar letters such as these "confusion classes". [This article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03328069) uses the term "acoustic similarity", which is basically a grand term for "rhyme".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found two sources that simply refer to these letters collectively as the "E-set":

> Two sets of letters were tested, the highly confusible **E-set**, `{B C D E
>   G T P V Z}`, and the full 26 letters.

—"[Speech Recognition using SVMs](https://books.google.com/books?id=GbC8cqxGR7YC&pg=PA1201&lpg=PA1201&dq=BCDEGPTVZ&source=bl&ots=ZwO2K05Et5&sig=Mha9Yv3AL_Lu3-0-sP6fn7uwPig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC66qRoIXNAhVGwmMKHZyNAEU4FBDoAQggMAI#v=onepage&q=BCDEGPTVZ&f=false)," Nathan Smith and Mark Gales, in *Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 14,* edited by Thomas Glen Dietterich, Suzanna Becker, Zoubin Ghahramani

> In the case of discriminating between minimal pairs, such as those in
>   the **E-set** vocabulary, (the letters {BCDEGTPVZ})...

—"[HMM Speech Recognition with Neural Net Discrimination](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/192-hmm-speech-recognition-with-neural-net-discrimination.pdf)," by William Y. Huang and Richard P. Lippmann

(Bolding added)

Comment: Thank you, @sumelic. *E-set vocabulary* is certainly a proper way to refer to them: it provides good context. I shall wait a while before accepting as it is not the word I remember from back in the day. But, for now, it is a solid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different search term.  Definitions are not what you want.

You'll find several links if you use the search term "spelling English letters."

If you use the term "phonetic spelling English letters" you will get several hits that use the IPA.